# Why does ReportLab not draw my lines where I want it to?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

sorry for the title. I'm not quite sure what the problem is, so I'm unable to express it more precisely.

I'm trying to replicate an existing form (only available on paper) using Python in ReportLab.

I measure the existing form and use the values to draw using ReportLab. Here is an example:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.lib.units import mm

def test():
    c = canvas.Canvas('test.pdf', pagesize=landscape(A4))
    h, w = A4

    c.line(21*mm, 37*mm, 278*mm, 37*mm) 

    c.showPage()
    c.save()
```

When I print this file (no scaling) and measure it, the line is not where it is supposed to be. It is horizontally offset to the right by about 5mm and vertically offset towards the top by about 3mm.

Why is that? Is there some border around the canvas/page that is not documented in the manual? Is the line wider than its visual representation?

I know that I can accomodate for this error by simply adding the offset in my code, but this is an already tedious task and I want to make sure that I am not missing some issue inherent to ReportLab or PDF generation in general.

Comment: How accurate is your printer? I'd first take a look inside the PDF and see if everything is in its place in there. Acrobat Pro has the necessary measuring tools.

Comment: Are you printing the file to printer onto A4 paper? If so, what corner of the paper are you measuring from? It should be the bottom-left of the page when it's held in landscape orientation (with the horizontal line near the bottom-left).

Answer (score 0):

**Draw a ruler in a page A4 or in pagesize as you mentioned and you can see these coordinates in your page and then you can draw line where ever you needed in your page based on plotted coordinates**
    def drawMyRuler(c):
        c.drawString(100,810, 'x100')
        c.drawString(200,810, 'x200')
        c.drawString(300,810, 'x300')
        c.drawString(400,810, 'x400')
        c.drawString(500,810, 'x500')

```
    c.drawString(10,100, 'y100')
    c.drawString(10,200, 'y200')
    c.drawString(10,300, 'y300')
    c.drawString(10,400, 'y400')
    c.drawString(10,500, 'y500')
    c.drawString(10,600, 'y600')
    c.drawString(10,700, 'y700')
    c.drawString(10,800, 'y800')
def test():
    c = canvas.Canvas('test.pdf', pagesize=landscape(A4))
    h, w = A4
    drawMyRuler(c)
    #remaining code as per drawMyRuler coordinates...
```

Comment: This does not help either the OP or a passer-by with the same predicament. Request you to add a little explanation to your solution to make it user friendly.